# can't display the students summary view but working fine in employee's view

Tags: php, laravel

I want to display the summary of student's transaction in one view from many relationship. My Employee's view is working fine

I downgrade the version of PHP and it's working fine in the employees transactions while in student's view it's not working

```
        @extends ('layouts.report')



    @section('content')


    <div id="breadcrumb">
        <div class="container"> 
            <div class="breadcrumb">                            
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{url('home')}}">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Reports</a></li> 
                <li>Search_Student</li>            
            </div>      
        </div>  
    </div>
    <br>
        <section id="reports">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">        
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebarLeft" role="navigation">
                                    <div class="well sidebar-nav">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-pill">    

                                            <li role="presentation"><a href="{{url('reports/hepa')}}" >HEPA-B</a></li>
                                            <li role="presentation"><a href="{{url('reports/referral')}}">REFERRAL</a></li>
                                            <li role="presentation"><a href="{{url('reports/med')}}">MEDICINE</a></li>
                                            <li role="presentation"><a href="{{url('reports/infirmary')}}">INFIRMARY</a></li>                        
                                            <li role="presentation"><a href="{{url('reports/physical')}}">PHYSICAL EXAM</a></li>
                                            <li role="presentation"><a href="{{url('reports/inhalation')}}">USN INHALATION</a></li>
                                            <li role="presentation"><a href="{{url('reports/wound')}}">WOUND DRESSING</a></li>
                                            <li role="presentation"><a href="{{url('reports/dental')}}">DENTAL-CHECK UP </a></li>
                                            <li role="presentation"><a href="" class="active">SEARCH STUDENT</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--/.well -->

                                </div>
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <!--hepa-->
                            <div class="active">
                                    <div class="panel panel-inf">                             
                                            <div class="panel-heading"><p><h4>STUDENT TRANSACTIONS</h4></p></div> 

                                            <form id="search-student" method="POST" role="search">
                                                @csrf
                                                <div class="form-inline mr-auto">
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search for Student ID" name="q"aria-label="Search">
                                            <button class="btn btn-mdb-color btn-rounded btn-sm my-0 ml-sm-2" type="submit">Search</button>
                                            </form>


                                        </div>
                                        <br>
                                        <div id="results-form">

                                        </div>
                                    </div>                                      
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

    </section>

    <script src="{{asset ('js/popper.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('js/bootstrap4_1.min.js')}}"></script>  
    <script src="{{asset ('js/wow.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset ('js/functions.js') }}"></script> 
    <script src="{{asset ('js/sweetalert2.all.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('js/bootstrap3_7.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/axios.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/toastr.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js') }}"></script>

    <script>
    $('#search-student').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var route = '{{ url('students/student_sview') }}';
        var data = $('#search-student').serialize();
        axios.post(route, data)
        .then(response => {
            $('#results-form').html(response.data);
        })
        .catch(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
        });
    });

    </script>

    @endsection 


<style>
    .img-with-text{
        text-align: left;
        width:100%;
        color: black;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    .img-with-text img{
        display:block;
        margin: none;
        height: 230px;
        width: 210px;

    }
    .grid-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
        grid-gap: 10px;
        background-color: #2196F3;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .grid-container>div {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
        text-align: center;
        padding:20px 0;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
</style>
<section id="search-student">
            <br>
        <div class="container"> 
                <div class="row">           
            @if($student != null)
            <div class="img-with-text">
                        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3">  
                <img src="{{URL::asset('/images/img_avatar2.png')}}" class="img-rounded" alt="" align="middle">
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">  



                <p><h4><b>Name: {{$student->firstname}}&nbsp;{{$student->middlename}}&nbsp;{{$student->lastname}}</b></h4></p>
                <p><h4><b>Year & Section: {{$student->dental[0]->yearSection}}</b></h4></p>   


                        </div>
            </div> 
            </div>
            <br>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-4">  
                    <table class="table table-striped">     
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">HEPA</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>     
                        @foreach($student->hepa as $hepa)

                        <tr>
                            <td class="rows">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{Carbon\Carbon::parse($hepa->created_at)->format('F d, Y h:m:s a')}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach 
                    </table> 
                        <table class="table table-striped">                    
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">MEDICINE</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>     
                        @foreach($student->med as $med)
                        <td class="rows">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{Carbon\Carbon::parse($med->created_at)->format('F d, Y h:m:s a')}}</td>
                        @endforeach
                        </table>
                        <table class="table table-striped">  
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">REFERRAL</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>     
                        @foreach($student->referral as $ref)
                        <td class="rows">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{Carbon\Carbon::parse($ref->created_at)->format('F d, Y h:m:s a')}}</td>
                        @endforeach
                        </table>

                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-4">  
                        <table class="table table-striped"> 
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">DENTAL</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead> 

                             @foreach($student->dental as $dental)
                            <tr>
                                <td class="rows">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{Carbon\Carbon::parse($dental->created_at)->format('F d, Y h:m:s a')}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </table>
                        <table class="table table-striped"> 
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">INHALATION</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>     
                            @foreach($student->usn as $usn)
                            <td class="rows">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{Carbon\Carbon::parse($usn->created_at)->format('F d, Y h:m:s a')}}</td>
                            @endforeach
                        </table>
                        <table class="table table-striped">  
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">PHYSICAL EXAM</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>     
                                @foreach($student->pe as $pe)
                                <td class="rows">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{Carbon\Carbon::parse($pe->created_at)->format('F d, Y h:m:s a')}}</td>
                                @endforeach
                                </table>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-4">  

                            <table class="table table-striped"> 
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">WOUND DRESSING</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead> 

                                @foreach($student->wound as $wound)
                                <td class="rows">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{Carbon\Carbon::parse($wound->created_at)->format('F d, Y h:m:s a')}}</td>
                                @endforeach
                            </table>
                            <table class="table table-striped"> 
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">INFIRMARY</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>     
                                @foreach($student->infi as $infi)
                                <td class="rows">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{Carbon\Carbon::parse($infi->created_at)->format('F d, Y h:m:s a')}}</td>
                                @endforeach

                            </table>
                        </div>


                @else
                <h5>No Results Found</h5>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>

</section>            

<!-- if no container ga error -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>Riverside College Clinic Management</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{asset('images/logo.png')}}" id="favicon">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <!-- <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script> -->

    <!-- Fonts -->

    <!-- Styles -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">  -->
    <link href="{{asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/font-awesome.min.css')}}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/animate.css')}}"/>
    <link href="{{asset('css/prettyPhoto.css')}}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="{{asset('css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" /> 
    <link href="{{asset('css/toastr.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet"/>   

    <script src="{{asset('js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js')}}"></script>
</head>
<style>
    img {

        border-radius: 50%;

    }
</style>
<body>

    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="navigation">

                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="navbar-brand">                          
                        <img src="{{URL::asset('/images/logo.png')}}" alt="img_logo" width="70" height="70" align="left" hspace="20"><h1>Clinic Management System</h1>                         
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">                          
                    <div class="menu">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                            <li role="navigation"><a href="{{url('home')}}">Home</a></li>
                            <li role="navigation"><a href="{{url('about')}}">About Us</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    Services
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{url('services')}}"><center>Students</center></a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{url('Employees/servicesEmp')}}">Employees</a>
                                </li>                    
                                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                        Reports
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{url('reports/hepa')}}"><center>Students</center></a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{url('EmpReport/EmpHepa')}}">Employees</a>
                                    </li>              
                                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                            <img src="{{URL::asset('images/'.auth()->user()->username.'.jpg')}}" alt="img_logo"  width="50" height="50" vertical-align="middle">
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-info" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink-4">
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My Account</a>                                                 
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{url('registerEmp')}}">Add Employee</a>  
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{url('registerStudent')}}">Add Student</a>   
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{url('register')}}">Add User</a>                                                                                    
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="showAlert()">Log Out</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <form action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" id="logout" style="display: hidden;">
                                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                                    </form> 

                                </li>       
                            </ul>

                        </div>
                    </div>                      

                </div>  
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div>@yield('content')</div>
        <script src="{{asset('js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/bootstrap3_7.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/respond.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/axios.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/sweetalert2.all.js')}}"></script>
        <link href="{{asset('css/toastr.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="{{asset('js/jquery.dataTables.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/dataTables.jqueryui.js')}}"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/integration/jqueryui/dataTables.jqueryui.css">


        <script type="text/javascript">
            function showAlert(){
                swal({
                    title: 'Are you sure?',
                    text: "You will be logged out of the system",
                    type: 'question',
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Yes'
                }).then((result) => {
                    if (result.value) {
                        $('#logout').submit();
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
        <script src="{{ asset('/js/axios.min.js') }}"></script>

    </body>


    </html>
```

For Employee

```
@extends ('layouts.report')

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">

@section('content')


<div id="breadcrumb">
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="breadcrumb">                            
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{url('home')}}">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Reports</a></li> 
            <li>Search_Employee</li>            
        </div>      
    </div>  
</div>
<br>
    <section id="reports">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">        
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebarLeft" role="navigation">
                                <div class="well sidebar-nav">
                                    <ul class="nav nav-pill">    

                                        <li role="presentation"><a href="{{url('EmpReport/EmpHepa')}}">HEPA-B</a></li>
                                        <li role="presentation"><a href="{{url('EmpReport/EmpReferral')}}">REFERRAL</a></li>
                                        <li role="presentation"><a href="{{url('EmpReport/EmpMedicine')}}">MEDICINE</a></li>
                                        <li role="presentation"><a href="{{url('EmpReport/EmpInfirmary')}}">INFIRMARY</a></li>
                                        <li role="presentation"><a href="{{url('EmpReport/EmpPe')}}">PHYSICAL EXAM</a></li>
                                        <li role="presentation"><a href="{{url('EmpReport/EmpInhalation')}}">USN INHALATION</a></li>
                                        <li role="presentation"><a href="{{url('EmpReport/EmpWound')}}">WOUND DRESSING</a></li>
                                        <li role="presentation"><a href="{{url('EmpReport/EmpDental')}}">DENTAL-CHECK UP</a></li>
                                        <li role="presentation"><a href="" class="active">SEARCH EMPLOYEE</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <!--/.well -->
                            </div>           
                                <div class="panel panel-inf">                             
                                    <div class="panel-heading"><p><h4>EMPLOYEE TRANSACTIONS</h4></p></div>  
                                        <form id="search-employee" method="POST" role="search">
                                                        @csrf
                                            <div class="form-inline mr-auto">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search for Employee ID" name="q"aria-label="Search">
                                        <button class="btn btn-mdb-color btn-rounded btn-sm my-0 ml-sm-2" type="submit">Search</button>
                                        </form>


</div>


                                                <br>
                                                <div id="results-form">

                                                </div>     
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</section>
```

I expect it will display the result but it's not working

Comment: hey, welcome to stackoverflow. for us to help you out, you need to provide us with a clear explanation and the codes required for us to debug, i am not sure what you want accomplished and what you error is here. and with the code provided, i dont see any relevance to employee view at all

Comment: hi thank you.i dont know what to do coz i'm new here.. basically, this is for my search view that will look for any student in my database. same code i'm using for my employee's transactions and it's working fine.

Comment: an easier way to explain it in a neater way is basically, by separating the controllers and the views. it'll be easier for people to read and understand the code then :)